# Wifi is Slow When Multiple Device Connected

Tags: wireless-networking

I have noticed that at home whenever I am using the wifi on my phone or laptop(to web surf, play games, or watch Youtube), and somebody else starts to use the wifi on their device, my own connection become awful (takes minutes to open a webpage, youtube starts to buffer).

How do i even begin to trouble shoot this? Is it a problem with the router, my internet provider, my configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Those are the classic symptoms of a common bug in modems, routers, and Wi-Fi APs, known as bufferbloat.

Go to http://dslreports.com/speedtest and get your bufferbloat grade.

If your residential broadband internet service is through a cable TV provider, make sure your modem is not on the badmodems.com list of modems with bad latency issues caused by the crappy Intel Puma 6 chipset.

If your modem/router/gateway is not on the list, then see if you can load OpenWrt on it and set up Cake, which uses FQ-CoDel to defeat bufferbloat. If not, consider buying an IQrouter from evenroute.com (it's a turn-key solution for bufferbloat for people that don't want to mess with OpenWrt themselves).

Some folks who don't really know networking deeply enough will recommend using QoS to prioritize some traffic over others, but that's just kludging around symptoms instead of attacking the root cause. Make sure your bufferbloat grade is an "A" before messing with traffic priorities.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, the configuration should be no problem, because when only your device is connected to wifi, we can use it normally.

There may be two reasons:

1.The network provider provides limited bandwidth and we confirm that the bandwidth is at least 10M-20M. If the bandwidth is not enough，we can try to purchase the high bandwidth usage.

2.If it has nothing to do with bandwidth, it is caused by the router. The router has limited ability to process data. We can try to replace wireless routers with higher throughput.